# std::vector emplace_back implementation

Tags: c++, vector

The push_back function that I implemented:

```
void push_back(T& num) {
    my_vec[index] = num;
    index++;
}
```

And the emplace_back function:

```
template<class... Args>
void emplace_back(Args&&... args) {
    push_back(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Do you see any problem with this? If yes then could you please tell me

Also, please let me know how does this work?

Please note: the emplace_back is not my implementation, I took it from other questions as I was looking for a way to implement my own emplace_back.

Comment: It doesn't accomplish the purpose of `emplace_back`, you either need to make `push_back` work with movable values or make `push_back` call `emplace_back`

Comment: The idea of `emplace_back` is to construct an element in-place, in raw memory. You're using just plain assignment, that's not what `emplace_back` is supposed to do even if it were a move assignment.

Comment: `emplace_back` use something called in placement new so your implementation is wrong.

Comment: It's not my implementation. I had already mentioned that. It was taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58881357/how-to-create-an-emplace-back-method

Answer (score 5):

> Do you see any problem with this?

You aren't really emplacing with this. There's still an assignment.

`std::vector<T>` *doesn't* allocate an array of `T`. It allocates raw memory with the size and alignment of an array of `T`, and then instantiates objects in that raw memory.

With that in mind, you should probably implement `push_back` in terms of `emplace_back`, rather than the other way around.

```
template <typename T>
class my_vector {
    T * start;
    std::size_t size;
    std::size_t capacity;

    void grow(); // Implementation of this is left as an exercise to the reader

public:
    template <typename... Args>
    reference emplace_back(Args&&... args) {
        if (size == capacity) grow();
        return *new (start + size++) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    reference push_back(const T & t) { return emplace_back(t); }
    reference push_back(T && t) { return emplace_back(std::move(t)); }
}
```

> Also, please let me know how does this work?

`template <typename... Args>` allows zero or more types to match this template, and then `T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` is constructing a `T` with those arguments, ["perfectly forwarding"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/what-are-the-main-purposes-of-using-stdforward-and-which-problems-it-solves) them, i.e. rvalues are passed as rvalues and lvalues as lvalues.

N.b. because `std::vector` doesn't `new[]`, you cannot implement something that behaves *exactly* like `std::vector` before C++ 20, because it has to be able to return a pointer to an array of `T` from `data` without constructing an array of `T`.

Answer (score 1):

The point of `emplace_back` is to construct an object in place. Your implementation constructs an object then copies it to `my_vec`.

Your implementation will not work with types that are not copyable. E.g. this won't compile:

```
Vector<std::thread> v;
v.emplace_back([](){});
v.push_back(std::thread([](){}));
```

Changing `push_back` to take it's argument via rvalue reference will fix the issue:

```
void push_back(T&& num) {
    my_vec[index] = std::move(num);
    index++;
}

template<class... Args>
void emplace_back(Args&&... args) {
    push_back(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

I think however that most standard library implementations are implemented using `emplace_back` as the lowest level function:

```
void push_back(T&& num) {
    emplace_back(std::move(num));
}

template<class... Args>
void emplace_back(Args&&... args) {
    my_vec[index] = T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    index++;
}
```

This then makes it easier to implement the `push_back` overload that copies the values:

```
void push_back(const T& num) {
    emplace_back(num);
}
```

Note that this implementation is using move assignment which is still not quite the intention of `emplace_back` which requires constructing an object in place using placement new on uninitialised memory but assuming `my_vec` is an array of objects or similar its the best you can do (without fully implementing the semantics of `std::vector` which is fairly complex).